# Where do I put mysql recover file?

Tags: mysql, command-line, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to migrate a mysql database from a server with phpMyAdmin to one that doesn't. I have a .sql file exported from the phpMyAdmin server, and am not quite sure where to go from there. While searching for an answer, I keep on finding websites that say to use this command:

```
mysql -u USER -p DBNAME < dump.sql
```

but nowhere describes WHERE that file should be located. Is it just supposed to be in the `var/lib/mysql` directory?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be anywhere. Use full path if not in the current directory

> mysql -u USER -p DBNAME <
>   /home/dump.sql

(if the file is in /home/ folder)

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Thanks for the correction, TehShrike.

You may follow `-p` with the password for user `USER` -- in which case there is no space between the option `p` and the password. Otherwise, mysql will prompt you for password. So the syntax is like the following:

```
mysql -u <user> -p<password> <database-name> < <path-to-mysqldump-file>
```

If the database does not already exist, you will have to login to your mysql server and create it first (Before the above line):

```
mysql -u <user> -p <password> 
create database <database-name>
```

Comment: If you just use the parameter -p then MySQL will prompt you for a password.  This is generally considered more secure than typing your password into the command line.

Comment: i think should be no space after `-p` ?

Comment: @TehShrike - not really, provided the space is removed

Comment: @ajreal - You're right, if you want to type your password into the command line, there should be no space between the -p and your password.  I don't quite understand what you mean when you say "not really" though.  My statement above is still correct.

Comment: @TehShrike - the statement is neither correct or wrong, imagine you want to perform automate backup, if not using `-p`, how to you get around that?